# Why is a comma captured in this group?

Tags: python, regex

I want write a python regex to match the number in a string consisting of a number followed by a comma. For instance, I want to match `34` within `34,`. However, the regex that I’m using matches the comma along with the number:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = r'^(\d+),?$'
>>> re.match(r, '123,').group(0)
'123,'
```

Why is python matching the comma when I excluded the comma from the capture group?

Comment: Because you didn't exclude the comma from the regex. If you don't want to match something, don't include it in the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group 0 is the entire regex — it will contain the entire string that was matched by the regex. The capturing groups [indicated with `(` and `)`] are numbered from 1.

To extract just the number, you can simply use `group(1)`:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = r'^(\d+),?$'
>>> re.match(r, '123,').group(1)
'123'
```

For more information about grouping, refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping).